# Several variables, differentiablity, continuity and primitive function

Tags: derivatives

Let $F_1 , F_2 : \mathbb{R^2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be functions defined by

$F_1 (x_1,x_2 )=-x_2/(x_1^2+x_2^2)$  and $F_2 (x_1,x_2 )=x_1/(x_1^2+x_2^2)$

Then

(i) $∂F_1/∂x_2=∂F_2/∂x_1.$

(ii) there exist a function $f: \mathbb{R^2}-{(0,0)}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that  $∂f/∂x_1=F_1$ and   $∂f/∂x_2=F_2$.

(iii) there exist no function $f: \mathbb{R^2}-{(0,0)}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that  $∂f/(∂x_1 )=F_1$ and  $∂f/(∂x_2 )=F_2$.

Comment: have a look on [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to make equations look beautiful.

Answer (score 0):

After computation i see that the option (i) is true .
Now see that the partial derivative are continuous and so $F_1$ and $F_2$ are differentiable. So by the property of primitive function there exists a function $f$ such that:

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}=F_1$$$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2}=F_2$$

But i am not sure about the existence of primitive function.
Can anyone help me?